# is django version 0.96 is compatiable with pyscopg2-2.0.7

Tags: django

am not able to sync the db...
manage.py syncdb is not working am getting follwing error

> D:\deepak\py\ifrnds>manage.py syncdb

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\deepak\py\ifrnds\manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management.py", line 1670, in
execute_manager
    execute_from_command_line(action_mapping, argv)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management.py", line 1569, in
execute_from_command_line
    action_mapping[action](int(options.verbosity), options.interactive)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management.py", line 504, in s
yncdb
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\bas
e.py", line 57, in cursor
    postgres_version = [int(val) for val in cursor.fetchone()[0].split()[1].spli
t('.')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,'
```

pls help me what to do....

Comment: Step one: Update to Django 1.1.1.

Comment: Step two: Check the documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/databases/#id1

Comment: Also, check this:http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs "If you’re using PostgreSQL, you’ll need the psycopg package. Django supports both version 1 and 2. (When you configure Django’s database layer, specify either postgresql [for version 1] or postgresql_psycopg2 [for version 2].)"

Answer (score 0):

typically a one word answer would get down votes. but i think everyone will agree on this one.

update!